# phpunit -d flag limitations?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

the manual says `phpunit -d key=val` allows any setting that is valid on the ini file. the exact same description of `php -d`

but for me it is doing absolutely nothing.

test using php alone:

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
var_dump( get_cfg_var('hello') );
?>

$ php -d hello=world test.php
string(5) "world"
```

all good! now what i get on phpunit:

```
$ cat test.php
<?php
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
        public function testA(){
                var_dump( get_cfg_var('hello') );
        }
}
?>

$ phpunit -d hello=world test.php
PHPUnit 3.7.35 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.bool(false)
```

how can i pass cfg_vars into phpunit via the command line?

Comment: have you already see [this](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/940)? I don't know if this can be a workaround for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-d` option set the ini variable using the `ini_set` function, has you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/TextUI/Command.php#L297).

So if you can change your code, you can take a value passed from the command line with the -c flag with the `ini_get`, as example try as follow:

```
    public function testA(){
            var_dump( ini_get('hello') );
    }
```

from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php) about `get_cfg_var`;

> get_cfg_var() will return strictly the server php.ini

Hope this help

Comment: `-c` is for a ini file. `-d` to inject key/values as if there were in the ini file. i have several tests, each depending on one server setting. i want to run them each time with a injected setting on the command line. right now i'm creating a ini file, running one test, repeat.

Comment: hi @gcb sorry is a typo, as referred the github link to the source code i tested for d flag