# How can I pass data to a phpunit test method?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am writing phpunit test case method which accept a parameter.

My code is as follows

```
class myTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMyCase($date){

        $resultSet=$this->query("select * from testCase where date='$date'");
        $this->assertTrue($resultSet,True);
    }
}
```

I am trying to run above test case from linux terminal.

```
phpunit --filter testMyCase myTestCase.php
```

But do not know how to pass parameter. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: mmm seems not possibile. Check this answer can help you in some manner https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467538/2270041

Comment: The second argument to `assertTrue()` is expected to be a `string`, see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6.3.0/src/Framework/Assert.php#L1148-L1151.

Comment: See https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should be using the most current version of PHPUnit (v6.x). The presence of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase makes it look like you're using an older version. But I digress...

You want a data provider.

```
class myTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
    * @dataProvider providerTestMyCase
    **/

    public function testMyCase($date, $expectedRowCount) {

        $sql  = "select * from testCase where date = '$date'";
        $stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute($sql);

        //We expect the query will always work.
        $this->assertTrue($result);

        //We are expecting the rowcount will be consistent with the expected rowcounts.
        $this->assertSame($expectedRowCount,$stmt->rowCount());
    }

    public funtion providerTestMyCase() {
        return [ [ '2017-08-01' , 76 ]
               , [ '2017-08-02' , 63 ]
               , [ '2017-08-03' , 49 ]
               , [ '2017-08-04' , 31 ]
               , [ '2017-08-05' , 95 ]
               ]
    }
}
```

Read and re-read: [Database Testing](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html) as well as [@dataProvider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.dataProvider)

Comment: Suggesting to use the most current version of `phpunit/phpunit` is ok, but there might be reasons not to be able to use the most recent version: `phpunit/phpunit:^6` requires `php: ^7.0`, but the project might require a version that doesn't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: 5.6 [lost active support 6 months ago](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). The [current best practice](http://www.phptherightway.com/#use_the_current_stable_version) is to use 7.x. If you're writing new code, it should be 7.0 compatible or else you're going to have some heartburn. [7 is faster](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/php7_infographic), more secure (uses libsodium as of 7.2), PHPUnit <6.0 is no longer supported. Staying on 5.6 just builds [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) into their project. Stay on 5.6 ONLY if you have no other choice.

Comment: I'm aware, but: I have been working on large  legacy projects for multi-million $$$ companies that initially had 0% test coverage, and there's no way of just switching to PHP7. There are a lot of reasons why upgrading is - not yet - possible, despite the potential benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need it.

```
class myTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMyCases()
    {
        $dates = [
            '2017-01-01 00:00:00',
            '2017-08-03 15:00:00'
        ];

        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $resultSet = $this->query("select * from testCase where date='$date'");
            $this->assertTrue($resultSet, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to use [@dataProvider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers), but the idea is correct - all tested permutations should be documented within the test case.

Answer (score -1):

Your test-method has a dependency on `$date`. You can give it a dataprovider (as outlined in an earlier answer) or make it dependent on another test-method which return the date.

```
...

function testDateDependency()
{
    $date = '...';
    $this->assertInternalType('string', $date, 'dependency check');

    return $date;
}

/**
 * @depends testDateDependency
 */
function testMyCase($date) {

    ...
```

These are the two options (the second one is the data-provider which is probably superior as you can more easily provide more different dependency values) I know of. The PHPUnit documentation might show more options.